# Custom Customer attribute that auto_increments

Tags: magento-1.9, module, customer-attribute, setup-script

I need a custom customer attribute of type int that should start with some 5-digit number and auto-increments each time a new customer is created.

**Approach 1:**
Or should I make a simple int type attribute and fill it with customer's auto generated ID plus some 5-digit number as follow.

```
customer_id = 30;
custom_id = 10030;
```

**Approach 2:**
Is there a way in magento to create an attribute of input type auto_increment? So I can set the default value to '10000' and it always get increment for new customer? If yes, then how can I make it auto_increment.

```
$installer->addAttribute('customer', 'cotp_id',  array(
    'type'     => 'int',
    'label'    => 'COTP ID',
    'input'    => 'hidden',
    'source'   => '',
    'visible'  => true,
    'required' => true,
    'default' => '10000',
    'frontend' => '',
    'unique'     => true,
    'note'       => 'Custom Attribute'
));
```

**Approach 3:**
Or should I try to achieve this through some observer that call upon every time a new customer created, then get the attribute latest/highest value and increment one in it?

Answer (score 3):

I am suggesting you to used Approach-3 with observer like this.

In your extension config.xml file avilabel  here.

```
app\code\[CodePool]\[Company]\[Extension]\etc\config.xml
```

define code like this:

```
<global>
        <events>
            <customer_save_after>
                <observers>
                    <Company_Extension_customer_save_after>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Company_Extension_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>customerRegisterSuccess</method>
                    </Company_Extension_customer_save_after>
                </observers>
            </customer_save_after>
        </events>
    </global>
```

create Observer.php at

```
app\code\[CodePool]\Company\Extension\Model\Observer.php

<?php
class Company_Extension_Model_Observer 
{
  public function customerRegisterSuccess(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) 
  {
      //Get Customer detail like 
      $customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer(); 

     // Here you need to add your logic to set that attribute value

  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks @Dhiren for your answer. But the observer you've mentioned is not observer when customer created from admin.

Comment: @MuhammadSaiid I edit my answer, if you talking about admin, then you need to used customer_save_after event.

Comment: If above answer help you, accept as solution, so other get help.

Comment: Yes thanks @Dhiren I get it. I hope it will be triggered for both admin and frontend customer registration.

Comment: if you want only for admin, then put event in <adminhtml> instade of <global>